# Putting value of "select" tag into JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

Sample of `<select>` HTML form element from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) (a bit modified):

```
<select>
  <option value="a">Option A</option>
  <option value="b">Option B</option>
  /*...*/
</select>
```

As far as I could see, neither `option` nor `select` has `id` property, so the good old `document.getElementById("name of select element").value` does not work.

But then, how can I put the `value` attribute of the option that is **selected** in the list into a JS variable?

I'm aware that it can be done by a function call, e.g. when I push a button element, but what do I have to write into that function?

Comment: @DevonBernard oh, thanks! Had no intention to write an actual duplicate, but I had a bit hard time finding relevant answers. Google refused to prefer SO questions somehow when I was searching.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from just giving it an id, you can add an onchange event:

```
<select onchange="yourfunction(this.value)">
...
```

There are also other ways to access elements in your DOM. For example, assuming this is the only (or first) select on your page you could access its value with a line like this:

```
var val = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an `id` to work with, the DOM provides a few other APIs that you can use, but probably the most versatile is:

```
 document.querySelector("CSS Selector Here");
```

So, you could use a selector that finds the `select` element by the tag name `select` or by its position in the DOM or by a class name applied to it, etc.

Then, to get the value, you'd write this:

```
 var val = document.querySelector("CSS Selector Here").selectedIndex.value;
```